# json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that I try to load like this:

```
import json
data = json.loads('test.json')
```

but it crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXXXX.py", line 61, in <module>
    data = json.loads('test.json')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When opening with vi the line looks ok:

```
{"922": {"ticket": {"problem": [{"id": ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your first stop should always be [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`json.loads` should accept a json string instead of the filename. In your case you need `json.load` with an opened file handle

```py
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Read the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.loads